# PC system repeats for 15 times keyboard's key strikes in random moments

Tags: motherboard, operating-systems, hardware-failure

I have a PC system with a really strange issue, I think it's hardware. While typing, at random moments and usually after repetitive strikes of any key, or fast typewriting, it repeats the last keystroke 15 times. For example, writing the word test, it stacks at `s` letter and types `tesssssssssssssss`. It is happening only using the keyboard and always but always, repeats 15 times.

None of the following helped:

- Changed keyboards. Three different brands of keyboards, USB keyboards, PS2 Keyboards.
- Removed every USB device even on-board using only PS2 keyboard.
- Changed all internal hardware except motherboard, hard disk drives and the box.
- Installed four different Windows versions, Windos 7 x64, Windows 7 x86, Windows Vista x86 and Windows XP x86.

I have also noticed, the issue is more frequent when working with two monitors. Plus every time that going to happen, stops for a second and then do the repetition.

Any idea what is this can be, or how to fix it?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows Seven 64 bit. But it is happening with Vista and XP too!!!

Comment: if its happening on multipls os and multiple h/w it quite likely somebody is playing a practical joke with you.
Try using a live cd like Ubuntu to see if it happens there too

Comment: In case that issue don't happens in Ubuntu, that means there is no hardware issue, what we have here??? Cause I am ready to get crazy with this thing. Is it possible to happens only in Microsoft OS, all of them? Isn't it a bit crazy?

Answer (score 3):

Try booting off a Linux LiveCD and see if the problem still occurs.  If it does, then you know its a hardware issue.  If it is a hardware issue, you might have to replace the motherboard.  If it does not occur, then you know its a software issue inside of Windows.

Comment: I have try using Ubuntu and as I remember it didn't "stack". But I am not sure, I'll try again. But if this issue has to do with windows, how it can happen in Windows 7 x64, Windows Vista x86 and Windows XP x86 too? Cause I have try all those OS... Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: Then I suspect it's a motherboard failure. What do you mean by it didn't "stack"? You should update the question to say that you've tried on all those operating systems.

Comment: I mean the repetition... I will update it yes. I just tried to boot using Ubuntu Live CD but I couldn't. After I choose to load I got black screen!!!